# How to make Notification in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to make Notification in Xamarin.Forms with XAML or C# Code?

Can I use this in Ios with Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Do you want real push notifications or local ones?

Comment: @AlmirVuk a local

Comment: Actually, you can't do a notification _with xaml_. Notifications are managed by the OS, you can only provide the values that it expects and the OS itself will handle the presentation. Often we use a dependency service (or a plugin that encapsulate this), calling it from the `C#` project's shared code

Comment: there are several plugins available to help manage notifications: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza okay thx for your support

Comment: @Jason okay thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the wonderful [Toasts.Forms.Plugin](https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin)

You can simply trigger a notification like this

```
var notificator = DependencyService.Get<IToastNotificator>();

var options = new NotificationOptions()
        {
            Title = "Title",
            Description = "Description"
        };
await notificator.Notify(options);
```

You can event react to if the user clicked, dismissed, etc. the notification

```
var result = await notificator.Notify(options);

// result is a NotificationResult with a NotificationAction in it
public enum NotificationAction
{
    Timeout = 1, // Hides by itself
    Clicked = 2, // User clicked on notification
    Dismissed = 4, // User manually dismissed notification
    ApplicationHidden = 8, // Application went to background
    Failed = 16 // When failed to display the toast
}
```

For android you are able to choose between `Snackbar` or `Notification` style. Have a look at the documentation to gain control to do your notification as you want!